# Should I put effort on learning Matlab if I already know and use Numpy/Scipy

Tags: matlab, numpy, scipy

I use and love Numpy and Scipy, but in one of the fields I'm involved (biomechanics research), MATLAB dominates the scene.

I believe this domination is pretty much due to tradition, similar to what happens with Windows or Office, but perhaps there is some intrinsic reason to prefer one over another.

Currently I can solve most problems of data analysis with Numpy/Scipy, but I see the awkwardness in the faces of researchers when I mention it.

The real question is: Is there a REAL NECESSITY to learn Matlab if I already know Numpy/Scipy?

Comment: Matlab is for professionals, Numpy/Scipy is for amateurs.  Choose which club you want to belong to.  I post this as a comment because it's an opinion and not an answer.  It's also an opinion which I'm not going to change whatever anyone else posts here :-)

Comment: "Matlab is for professionals, Numpy/Scipy is for amateurs." <--- This is categorically false.  Just expressing my **opinion** too!

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I guess there are a lot of amateurs running around in the research community solving all sorts of really hard problems with numpy/scipy. Who would have thought they could have accomplished so much belonging to such a meager club.

Comment: (Regarding closing this question, I thought it might happen and don't care that much, but since I have already read lots of similar X vs. Y questions in SO, and they always helped a lot as information gathering prior to an informed decision, I'd ask to let some more answers and comments to get in BEFORE actually closing. Thanks.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say you apply for work in my lab. You say "I know Numpy/Scipy". Then I say "That's awesome, then it will be much easier for you to learn Matlab". Why? Because our code-base is in Matlab, our collaborators' code-base is in Matlab, and I won't pay you to re-invent the wheel, and I won't pay you to write code that cannot easily be integrated into other people's projects.

In short: If a field is mainly using one language, and you want to work in that field, then it is very useful to know that language.

Comment: Although the first paragraph is sort of rough, the last one pretty much hits the point. +1 and waiting to possibly accept.

Answer (score 2):

The right answer really depends on your situation.

Leaning Matlab to prevent funny faces during presentations is **not** the right reason to lean the language.  If someone can't accept your results because you used Python instead of Matlab they are demonstrating their weakness as a scientific peer.  They should judge you work based upon the data, results, and interpretation of those results.  If you implement your models correctly the language you used to implement them should have **no** effect on the results, if it does then there is a problem with your model.

However, if work in your field is collaborative you will probably be better off learning the language of your peers. You want your peers to incorporate your work into their own work.  Sadly many of them will assume that translating Python to Matlab will be too high a barrier for entry, and give up.

So only you can decided if its a necessity to learn Matlab, although it probably will be advantageous.

Comment: It is interesting that, at the same time when judges look skeptically at an open-source library (after all, who knows what code is inside, and if it is doing things right?), they take for granted that, only because an analysis has been ran on COMMERCIAL software, it is automatically trustworthy. I am not saying Matlab is bad, or Numpy is bad, but I think "Garbage-In-Garbage-Out" prevention is much more reliant on people and research methods than on tools, and anyway no one knows for sure what's inside Matlab source code, after all...

Answer (score 1):

It never hurts to learn new programming languages. You can only make yourself better by learning. So the question comes down to you wanted to put effort into learning MatLab.

Answer (score 1):

Pros for Numpy/Scipy

- Faster than MATLAB, especially if there are really big for-loops (or nested for-loops) in your code. MATLAB has highly optimized matrix manipulation stuff though and I think they also have a parallelized for (parfor)
- Free
- No licensing issues so you can run like a thousand instances of your code and not have to worry about having a thousand licenses to go with it.

Pros for MATLAB:

- MATLAB just has a lot of really great built in packages (like the entire stats toolbox for instance).
- MATLAB is good for making pretty plots efficiently (if you know Matplotlib then forget this Pro).
- Everyone in your industry currently uses it. You can attribute this to people's unwillingness to learn how to program, or some group stubbornness or tradition, etc... but it doesn't change these two things: (1) you will probably be able to learn MATLAB faster than they can learn python and (2) your goals are better met if you can effectively communicate and be part of a wider community of researchers...yes?

Comment: I actually disagree with the point that MATLAB is slower. Mathworks, over the last few years, has added a great deal of optimizations to Matlab. Well written code, even with for loops, can be extremely efficient and approach speeds on the same order of magnitude with C.

Comment: Looks like Matlab has some compiling infra-structure built-in.

Comment: @heltonbiker Yes there is a JIT-accelerator in MATLAB, although there is no official documentation: see this [answer](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/2321#answer_3600) in MATLAB Central.

Comment: @thewopr - I said this from personal experience - if I execute a for-loop 1e6 times in MATLAB it is terrible for me. But in python, i can do it. And that's *after* vectorizing everything possible in MATLAB. But I understand this point is contentious. Point taken.

Answer (score 1):

I use and love both Numpy/Scipy and MATLAB, and in my opinion they are complementary, with far less overlapping than is usually assumed by the occasional user.

Yes, I think that it is really necessary for you to learn MATLAB, at least to verify if my unjustified assertion above is true or not.